# Parallel.Foreach with shared absolute index for all the parallel processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I'm running a process which, for example, works on 10 files at a time. I need to assign a serial number based on the input order of the input file array. So, for each parallel process, I need to assign the serial numbers to be used in the parallel process in the same order as the input string array `myFiles`. Do I need some type of threadsafe or concurrent int? What's the correct approach?

```
var results = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var options = new ParallelOptions
    { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };
int startSerialNumber = 1;
if (runParallel)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(myFiles, options, (myFile) =>
    {
        var newMyFile = WorkOnMyFile(myFile,startSerialNumber);
        startSerialNumber += SubFileCount; // <--This needs to be shared
            // for all parallel processes where how do I control incrementing?
        results.Enqueue(RunExeTask(newMyFile, outputDirectory,false));
    });
}
```

Comment: Try using the Interlocked.Add() method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @LordPupazz Thanks, That looks like the right mechanism, but how do ensure the `startSerialNumber` value won't be incremented by another process before `WorkOnMyFile` is executed?

Comment: When in doubt? Lock the whole operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: As a side note, determining the concurrency level of a primarily I/O operation by the number of available processors is not a great idea. Although there is certainly a statistical correlation between having a fast CPU and a fast storage hardware, it is not at all impossible to encounter a super fast PC equipped with an outdated hard disk, or a slow laptop connected to a blazingly fast SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the serial numbers outside of the parallel processing. Incrementing a number is trivial so it's not like you need to do it on multiple threads. As you generate them, pair them with the items in your list to create a new list containing both, then iterate over that.

```
var myData = myFiles
    .Select
    (
        (f, i) => new { File = f, SerialNumber = startingSerialNuber + (i * SubFileCount) }
    )
    .ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(myData, options, (myItem) =>
{
    myFile = myItem.File;
    serialNumber = myItem.SerialNumber;
    var newMyFile = WorkOnMyFile(myFile,serialNumber);
    results.Enqueue(RunExeTask(newMyFile, outputDirectory,false));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) instead of the `Parallel` class, because the former is inherently able to collect thread-safely the processed results, and return them (optionally) in their original order. It also makes easy to get the index of the currently processed item, by using the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.select#System_Linq_ParallelEnumerable_Select__2_System_Linq_ParallelQuery___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload that accepts an index:

```
public static ParallelQuery<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult> (
    this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector);
```

Usage example:

```
string[] results = myFiles
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered() // Optional, by default the original order will not be preserved
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(runParallel ? Environment.ProcessorCount : 1)
    .Select((myFile, index) =>
    {
        var newMyFile = WorkOnMyFile(myFile, index);
        return RunExeTask(newMyFile, outputDirectory, false);
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
    var results = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };
    int startSerialNumber = 1;
    if (runParallel)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(myFiles, options, (myFile) =>
                {
                    var newMyFile = WorkOnMyFile(myFile, startSerialNumber);
                    Interlocked.Add(ref startSerialNumber, SubFileCount);
                results.Enqueue(RunExeTask(newMyFile, outputDirectory, false));
                });
            }).Wait();
        }).Start();
    }
```

Essentially this runs your operation on a background thread that waits for a task to complete before carrying on. As long as you don't reference startSerialNumber anywhere else you should be fine.

Comment: There is absolutely 0 reason to use `new Thread` or `Task.Run`.